# How to create a description list type of content with Magnolia 5.6

Tags: content-management-system, headless, magnolia

Magnolia has a few classes that you can use in order to describe the form/dialog that you want the content editor to work with, however I have not found a functioning way to create a description list as a MultiValue field.

Aiming to create a component like an FAQ, where the user would add as many items as they would like, where each item has two fields - the question and the answer. Then later perhaps an optional image.

How can I achieve this with Magnolia? Below is my most sensible attempt.

```
form:
  label: FAQ list
  tabs:
    - name: tabMain
      label: Q/A
      fields:
        - name: list
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.MultiValueFieldDefinition
          label: Q/A
          field:
            name: qaField
            class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.CompositeFieldDefinition
            label: Q/A
            fields:
              - name: question
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
                label: Question
              - name: answer
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
                label: Answer
```

---

Below is the error log, and I do the following to cause it:

- Go to my page
- Edit the component for my light-module
- Magnolia shows me a short red error message (details below)

> 2018-01-22 19:09:15,230 ERROR info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.PageEditorPresenter: An error occurred while executing action [editComponent]
>   info.magnolia.ui.api.action.ActionExecutionException: Action execution failed for action: editComponent
>       at info.magnolia.ui.api.action.AbstractActionExecutor.execute(AbstractActionExecutor.java:64) ~[magnolia-ui-api-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.PageEditorPresenter.onAction(PageEditorPresenter.java:175) [magnolia-pages-app-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.editor.PageEditor$1.editComponent(PageEditor.java:102) [magnolia-pages-editor-widget-5.6.jar:5.6]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1568) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:381) [vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.AdmincentralVaadinServlet.service(AdmincentralVaadinServlet.java:147) [magnolia-ui-admincentral-5.6.jar:?]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ServletDispatchingFilter.doFilter(ServletDispatchingFilter.java:148) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.virtualuri.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:98) [magnolia-virtual-uri-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:58) [magnolia-cache-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.CompositeExecutor.processCacheRequest(CompositeExecutor.java:67) [magnolia-cache-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:220) [magnolia-cache-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:89) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:77) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:84) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119) [magnolia-site-1.2.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73) [magnolia-cache-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:127) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:155) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:110) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:96) [magnolia-core-5.6.jar:?]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.5]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
>   Caused by: com.vaadin.v7.data.Buffered$SourceException
>       at com.vaadin.v7.ui.AbstractField.setPropertyDataSource(AbstractField.java:641) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.AbstractCustomMultiField.createLocalField(AbstractCustomMultiField.java:175) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.MultiField.createEntryComponent(MultiField.java:177) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.MultiField.initFields(MultiField.java:159) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.MultiField.initFields(MultiField.java:75) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.AbstractCustomMultiField.initFields(AbstractCustomMultiField.java:134) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.MultiField.initContent(MultiField.java:145) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at com.vaadin.v7.ui.CustomField.getContent(CustomField.java:99) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.v7.ui.CustomField.attach(CustomField.java:89) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.BaseDialogViewImpl.attach(BaseDialogViewImpl.java:186) ~[magnolia-ui-dialog-5.6.jar:?]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:550) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.magnoliashell.MagnoliaShell.addOverlay(MagnoliaShell.java:221) ~[magnolia-ui-vaadin-common-widgets-5.6.jar:5.6]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.magnoliashell.MagnoliaShell.openOverlay(MagnoliaShell.java:191) ~[magnolia-ui-vaadin-common-widgets-5.6.jar:5.6]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.framework.shell.ShellImpl.openOverlayOnView(ShellImpl.java:221) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.SubAppContextImpl$1.openOverlay(SubAppContextImpl.java:150) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.framework.context.AbstractUIContext.openOverlay(AbstractUIContext.java:66) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormDialogPresenterImpl.start(FormDialogPresenterImpl.java:154) ~[magnolia-ui-dialog-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormDialogPresenterImpl.start(FormDialogPresenterImpl.java:129) ~[magnolia-ui-dialog-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.pages.app.action.EditElementAction.execute(EditElementAction.java:121) ~[magnolia-pages-app-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.api.action.AbstractActionExecutor.execute(AbstractActionExecutor.java:62) ~[magnolia-ui-api-5.6.jar:?]
>       ... 96 more
>   Caused by: com.vaadin.v7.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type java.lang.String to presentation type class com.vaadin.v7.data.util.PropertysetItem. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
>       at com.vaadin.v7.data.util.converter.ConverterUtil.convertFromModel(ConverterUtil.java:128) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.v7.ui.AbstractField.convertFromModel(AbstractField.java:712) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.v7.ui.AbstractField.convertFromModel(AbstractField.java:697) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.v7.ui.AbstractField.setPropertyDataSource(AbstractField.java:633) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.AbstractCustomMultiField.createLocalField(AbstractCustomMultiField.java:175) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.MultiField.createEntryComponent(MultiField.java:177) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.MultiField.initFields(MultiField.java:159) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.MultiField.initFields(MultiField.java:75) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.AbstractCustomMultiField.initFields(AbstractCustomMultiField.java:134) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.form.field.MultiField.initContent(MultiField.java:145) ~[magnolia-ui-form-5.6.jar:?]
>       at com.vaadin.v7.ui.CustomField.getContent(CustomField.java:99) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.v7.ui.CustomField.attach(CustomField.java:89) ~[vaadin-compatibility-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.BaseDialogViewImpl.attach(BaseDialogViewImpl.java:186) ~[magnolia-ui-dialog-5.6.jar:?]
>       at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:626) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:629) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:550) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.5.jar:8.1.5]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.magnoliashell.MagnoliaShell.addOverlay(MagnoliaShell.java:221) ~[magnolia-ui-vaadin-common-widgets-5.6.jar:5.6]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.magnoliashell.MagnoliaShell.openOverlay(MagnoliaShell.java:191) ~[magnolia-ui-vaadin-common-widgets-5.6.jar:5.6]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.framework.shell.ShellImpl.openOverlayOnView(ShellImpl.java:221) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.SubAppContextImpl$1.openOverlay(SubAppContextImpl.java:150) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.framework.context.AbstractUIContext.openOverlay(AbstractUIContext.java:66) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormDialogPresenterImpl.start(FormDialogPresenterImpl.java:154) ~[magnolia-ui-dialog-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormDialogPresenterImpl.start(FormDialogPresenterImpl.java:129) ~[magnolia-ui-dialog-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.pages.app.action.EditElementAction.execute(EditElementAction.java:121) ~[magnolia-pages-app-5.6.jar:?]
>       at info.magnolia.ui.api.action.AbstractActionExecutor.execute(AbstractActionExecutor.java:62) ~[magnolia-ui-api-5.6.jar:?]
>       ... 96 more

Comment: What’s not functional on the definition you attached? Looks like it would do the job just fine.

Comment: Magnolia crashes and there's an error, the error you get when you have incorrect definitions. I can get back with more details on the error.

Comment: Yes please. Add the exact error you get. Also the empty line in the definition above after “fields:” is it just formatting of the post or do you really have it there?

Comment: @Jan I added the error above, and removed the empty line. It was there, but it doesn't seem like that is what caused this problem.